# Why does $.each show only one of my Mustache templates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, mustache

I'm using `$.get` inside `$.each` to call an external Mustache template to use on each Photo object in my array.

Here is my code:

```
$.when.apply($, requests).then(function(dataOne, dataTwo) {
    $.each(dataOne, function(idx, obj) {
        $.get("myTemplate.mst", function(template) {
            var rendered = Mustache.render(template, obj);

            $photoElem.html(rendered);
        });
    });
});
```

My problem is that once I refresh the screen, only one of my array objects shows up. I'm aware of `{{#item}}` to iterate through the array but I'm using `$.each` for a very specific reason.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As a side-note: for efficiencies-sake you should `get` the template one time only and assign it to a variable to be used for all the photos.

Comment: what is $photoElem? Give more information . Suppose problem causes you replace content of $photoElem ( using .html() ) instead of appending each new item

Comment: Hey @VasilVanchuk $photoElem is just the cached `$(".PhotoElem")` container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
 $.when.apply($, requests).then(function(dataOne, dataTwo) {
      $.get("myTemplate.mst", function(template) {
          $.each(dataOne, function(idx, obj) {
             var rendered = Mustache.render(template, obj);
             $photoElem.append(rendered);
         });
     }); 
 });
```

Suppose problem causes you replace content of $photoElem ( using .html() ) instead of appending each new item

I replace .html() with .append(

And change code to read template only once ( as @Andy say )

Comment: That was quick. It actually makes sense why `.html()` didn't work, I was replacing every object I put inside the object with each iteration. Thanks Vasil.